# Strange TFS Source Repository Problem

Tags: version-control, tfs

We have a web project we are working on using TFS and we are kind of new to it (TFS).  One of my teammates is unable to see a particular page (three associated files) in the IDE.  To the rest of us, it looks as though it is checked out to her.  When she ran the unlock command through the console, it returned that the files for the page were not locked.  Yet we are unable to check it out due to her apparently having a lock.

Any thoughts, ideas, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This may be unrelated, but there's a known issue with TFS which causes items to appear checked out when this isn't necessarily the case:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/tfsversioncontrol/thread/2a1c6a8c-0a2b-460c-9335-e31598f1107b

Usually whenever TFS throws an error like this, you should be able to clear it by deleting the local copy and doing a full get latest.  At least, that's worked for me in the past ..